# CSS Media Query is not evaluated until browser refresh

Tags: css, polymer, media-queries

I have this stylesheet in a polymer component:

```
<style include="app-grid-style">
  :host {
     --app-grid-columns: 1;
     --app-grid-gutter: 10px;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    :host {
       --app-grid-columns: 2;
       --app-grid-gutter: 15px;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
    :host {
      width: 90%;
      --app-grid-columns: 4;
      --app-grid-gutter: 30px;
    }
  }

  paper-button {
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    color: var(--app-dark-primary-color, black);
  }

  .header {
    @apply(--paper-font-headline);
    color: var(--app-dark-gray-color);
  }

  .header-icon {
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  p {
    color: var(--app-light-gray-color);
  }
</style>
```

Ok, it seems the media queries are fine, because if I resize the browser and refresh, I see the page with the changes or if I access to the page from my iPhone, I see the site for smarphones.

However, I think I must see how the css change the page when I resize the browser without I have to reload the page.

Are there any bug in my stylesheet?

Comment: :host is not a valid selector

Comment: Do you mean ":host" is not a valid selector for media-queries? ":host" is included in polymer elements, and in polymer app-grid-layout documentation is used like me: [link](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/master/app-grid/demo/md-grid-layout.html)

Comment: This usualy happens on chrome, try using firefox

Comment: @RamSegev I tried in Safari and doesn't work :(

Comment: @staypuftman you are right, I modified the <p> style in the same media queries and works... but I don´t understand why with :host doesn't work, because in polymer element documentation it works...

Comment: @staypuftman: [Sure it is.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#host-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have found the solution in polymer documentation. I think it's a bit hidden:

"For browsers that don't support custom properties, call Polymer.updateStyles() to re-evaluate the media queries upon window resize" - For more information: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/release-notes#v-1-6-0

Analyzing the example in documentation, I have found they call that method in attached function on polymer element.

I have tried this fix and it's works!